# variable assignment is delayed when called via an Interface in Java

Tags: java, android, function, interface, variable-assignment

For the code given below, string `receivedResponse` is not assigned immediately when called from interface function. I found out that, to assign the string `response` in `receivedResponse`, I have to call the function `onCurrentResponse()` again. I will highly appreciate to know the reason behind that. If it is possible to fix the issue somehow, that will be better. The following code is sufficient to reproduce the error. Please have a look:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private NetworkManager networkManager;
String receivedResponse;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    networkManager = new NetworkManager(this);
}

public void handleClick(View view){
    networkManager.getResponseFromNetwork(callback);
    System.out.println("Response in 'receivedResponse' is: " + receivedResponse); // I am getting 
//null value when called for the first time

}
private final NetworkManager.ServiceCallback callback = new NetworkManager.ServiceCallback() {

    @Override
    public void onCurrentResponse(@NonNull String response) {
        receivedResponse = response; // I have to call this function again to assign the response 
 string
        System.out.println("Response in 'response' is: " + response);
    }
};
}

class NetworkManager {
private final RequestQueue queue;
public NetworkManager(@NonNull final Activity activity) {
    queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(activity.getApplicationContext());
}
public interface ServiceCallback {
    @MainThread
    void onCurrentResponse(@NonNull final String response);
}
public void getResponseFromNetwork(final ServiceCallback callback) {
            final String url = "https://www.themealdb.com/api/json/v1/1/random.php";
    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url,
            callback::onCurrentResponse, error -> System.out.println("Some error")
    );
    queue.add(stringRequest);
}
}
```

Comment: Network requests are asynchronous, it means you send request, and will get result at some time in the future, in callback, in `onCurrentResponse()` in your case. `receivedResponse` will be null in `handleClick()`, because network request wasn't finished yet, and will be set in `onCurrentResponse()`

Comment: Hello, @SergeyGlotov Thank you for your answer. So, how do I make sure network request is finished so that I can update UI after the request is finished?

Comment: The problem I am having is that, system.out in onCurrentResponse() is running before system.out in getResponseFromNetwork() which is bad in this case. So, I need help to make sure system.out in onCurrentResponse() is running after getResponseFromNetwork(). @SergeyGlotov

Comment: "So, how do I make sure network request is finished so that I can update UI after the request is finished?" You will get callback

Comment: "So, I need help to make sure system.out in onCurrentResponse() is running after getResponseFromNetwork()." 1. Why do you need it? 2. There's no `println` in `getResponseFromNetwork()` excepting error case, which shouldn't be called in normal situation

Comment: First of all, sorry for the confusion I created by incorrectly referring handleClick() as getResponseFromNetwork().
1. I wanted to run printlln in handleClick() as I would be updating UI with the information received from network.
2. I know. My bad.

For now, I figured out to use the response I am receiving from onCurrentResponse(). So, now, my problem is kinda sorted out. :) Thanks for your info @SergeyGlotov